# Rails: group_by then map children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, vue.js

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def categorised_templates
  template_categories.all_parents.map do |cat|
    cat.templates.by_brand(id).group_by(&:category)
  end
end
```

Which returns something like this:

```
[{"Communications":["#<Template:0x00007fef0efcdd48>","#<Template:0x00007fef0efcdb90>"]},{"Beta":["#<Template:0x00007feefe1bb008>"]}]
```

How can I render the `Template` objects into JSON just like the categories? I need to maintain the `group_by` hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was easy enough. This change:

```
def categorised_templates
  arr = template_categories.all_parents.map do |cat|
    cat.templates.by_brand(id).group_by(&:category)
  end

  arr.map { |cat| cat.transform_values!(&:to_s) }
end
```

Returns this result.

```
[{"Communications":"[#<Template id: 2, ...]"}]
```